# Mist not syncing

Tags: mist, synchronization

I need help. Ive downloaded the latest MIST 0.8.9 on my Mac. Ive sent Ether to my wallet but it is not showing up 0x64D18245635BC6380f3d879B3ac1AFA2c3c1E063

On the bottom left it is showing 
"your latest block number 0" 
"0 peers" 
"Elapsed time since last block 47 years"

Can somebody help me?

Thank you very much